# Unrecognized selector sent to instance" problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

my code broke somewhere along the way, and crashes when using the navigation bar buttons.

Error message:
`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView newMemoViewController:didAddMemo:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5b55a60'`

When debugging, the program does run the `cancel` method, and throws an exception at the `@synthesize` line. However, I cannot see anything wrong with it.

The symptoms are identical, so I am including the relevant code only for the `Cancel` button:

**NewMemoViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol NewMemoDelegate;


@class AKVoiceMemo;


@interface NewMemoViewController : UIViewController {
    @private
        AKVoiceMemo *voiceMemo;
        id <NewMemoDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) AKVoiceMemo *voiceMemo;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <NewMemoDelegate> delegate;

@end

@protocol NewMemoDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)newMemoViewController:(NewMemoViewController *)newMemoViewController didAddMemo:(AKVoiceMemo *)voiceMemo;


@end
```

**NewMemoViewController.m**

```
#import "NewMemoViewController.h"

@synthesize delegate;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UIBarButtonItem *cancelButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancel)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButtonItem;
    [cancelButtonItem release];
}


- (void)cancel {
    [self.delegate newMemoViewController:self didAddMemo:nil];
}
```

Your help would be appreciated.

**Edit**: the delegate is the `RootViewController`:

```
- (void)newMemoViewController:(NewMemoViewController *)newMemoViewController didAddMemo:(AKVoiceMemo *)voiceMemo {
    if (voiceMemo){
        // Show the note in a new view controller
        // TODO: Implement this
    }

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're probably setting the delegate of `NewMemoViewController` to a `UIView` object instead of an object that implements the `NewMemoDelegate` protocol.

The error message is telling you that a `newMemoViewController:didAddMemo:` message was sent to a `UIView` object and the `UIView` object didn't know what to do with it. Since your `cancel` method calls `newMemoViewController:didAddMemo:` on the delegate, it is the *delegate* which is the `UIView` object that doesn't recognize the `newMemoViewController:didAddMemo:` message. In other words, your delegate is a `UIView` and it doesn't implement the `NewMemoDelegate` protocol.

If you are correctly setting the delegate, then @jtbandes makes a great point: The delegate is probably being released and a `UIView` object is taking over the same memory location, thus "becoming" the delegate by accident. You're doing the right thing by using the `assign` attribute for your delegate; that's fairly standard Cocoa practice. However, you do need to make sure that the delegate is retained by another object, and *that* object needs to make sure that the delegate sticks around as long as `NewMemoViewController` needs it to.

Comment: Hi James, I have added the code from the RootViewController as well.
Forgot to add the line from the header:

@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, NewMemoDelegate>


Let me know if I am missing something

Comment: What object are you setting as the delegate?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean -- the delegate is the root view controller, which does implement the `NewMemoDelegate` protocol. When the app crashes, `self.delegate` **IS** in fact a `UIView`, but I don't understand why. I appreciate your help, but you might need to spoon-feed me with the resolution, as I am a rookie in delegation (and programming itself)

Comment: If you are setting the root view controller as the delegate (in code or in Interface Builder), then @jtbandes is probably right. The delegate (root view controller) is probably being released somewhere. Objects typically don't retain their delegate, which means that some other object needs to make sure the delegate isn't released prematurely. Is some object retaining your root view controller? For more information, check out Delegates and Data Sources in Apple's Cocoa Fundamentals Guide.

Comment: Yes, I think the Core Data database should retain it. Both the `NSFetchedResultsController` and the `NSManagedObjectContext` use the `retain` specifiers.

Comment: You're putting your root view controller into Core Data? That's kind of weird. It might help for you to go through a simple iPhone app tutorial to see how view controllers are typically created and retained. The solution is probably simple, like having your application delegate retain your root view controller (or retain the navigation controller containing your root view controller), but understanding the design patterns used in Cocoa will help you in lots of places.

Comment: Hm. My root view controller is a `UITableViewController` and it is the main screen of the application -- it is connected to the Core Data database, and lists the data from it. It is this controller that passes on the data to other views. I thought this was the way it was supposed to work, and I didn't run into any problems so far.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you've over-released the delegate. I notice you have `@property (assign) ... delegate;`. This means that whenever you set the delegate, that object must be retained by something else as well.

The other possibility is the delegate is actually a UIView, but I'm guessing it's the other case.