# How to update the selected property of a UIButton using the button's tag

Tags: ios, uibutton

I am trying to update the selected property for a UIButton by using the button’s tag.  However, when I select the relevant view in the iOS simulator I get the following error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setSelected:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x995b1e0'

---

After researching this issue and error, it appears that the UIView object doesn't know what to do with the setSelected method.

Here is my code where I am attempting to update the selected property:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"Documents folder: %@", [self documentsDirectory]);
    NSLog(@"Data file path:%@", [self dataFilePath]);

    UIButton *januarybtn = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];

    [januarybtn setSelected:YES];

}
```

Also, here are several posts that I have tried to follow when making this update:

[UIView viewWithTag 0 problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540012/uiview-viewwithtag-0-problem)

[Unrecognized selector sent to instance" problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631616/unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-problem)

Thank you in advance for helping me.

Comment: the view with tag "1" seems not to be a UIButton .. Debug and you'll see.

Comment: Put `NSLog(@"view with tag 1: %@", [self.view viewWithTag:1]);` with your other NSLog statements and make sure it's actually returning a button.

Comment: Here is the result of the NSLog statement:                            2013-12-11 23:35:21.845 Medtrack[81107:70b] view with tag 1: <UIButton: 0x9939c70; frame = (31 29; 82 53); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x99435d0>>

Comment: After running the NSLog statement and determining that the UIButton was returning I reviewed my code. I made an error and had the tag of the button mismatched. Thank you for helping me debug this issue.